# Determine subplot square dimensions from total number of plots

Tags: algorithm, python-3.5, dimensions, subplot

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate subplot dimensions when I know the total number of plots I need and I'd like the arrangement to be a square (with possibly a few empty subplots).

For example if I need 22 subplots then I would make a grid of `5x5` for a total of 25 subplots, then just leave three of them empty.

So I guess I'm looking for an algorithm where I'd input 22 and get out 5, for example. Anyone know of a short way to do this in python (maybe lambda function if possible)?

(Also open to other alternatives or pre-made solutions for doing this, I'm doing multiple subplot matrices for a dictionary of pandas dataframes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you're trying to do. I haven't tried anything with a lambda function but I doubt it would be difficult to modify this. There won't be any empty plots because the algorithm stops once it's out of values to plot.

I broke up the dictionary into key and value lists because I was originally working with lists when I wrote this. Everything up to the try clause would work without converting your values to a list. If you wanted to fill in with empty plots rather than using the somewhat hack-y break_test bit, you can put all of your code for the subplots inside a try clause.

Weird break version:

```
fig = plt.figure()

# Makes organizing the plots easier
key_list, val_list = [k, v for k, v in dict.getitems()]

# We take advantage of the fact that int conversions always round down
floor = int(np.sqrt(len(val_list))

# If the number of plots is a perfect square, we're done.
# Otherwise, we take the next highest perfect square to build our subplots
if floor ** 2 == len(val_list):
    sq_chk = floor
else:
    sq_chk = floor + 1

plot_count = 0

# The try/except makes sure we can gracefully stop building plots once 
# we've exhausted our dictionary values.
for i in range(sq_chk):
    for j in range(sq_chk):
        try:
            break_test = val_list[plot_count]
        except:
            break

        ax = fig.add_subplot(sq_chk, sq_chk, plot_count + 1)
        ax.set_title(key_list[plot_count])

        ...
        # Whatever you want to do with your plots
        ...

        plot_count += 1

plt.show()
```

No break version:

```
fig = plt.figure()
key_list, val_list = [k, v for k, v in dict.getitems()]

floor = int(np.sqrt(len(dict))

if floor ** 2 == len(dict):
    sq_chk = floor
else:
    sq_chk = floor + 1

plot_count = 0

# Everything from the original snippet should be nested in the try clause
for i in range(sq_chk):
    for j in range(sq_chk):
        try:

            ax = fig.add_subplot(sq_chk, sq_chk, plot_count + 1)
            ax.set_title(key_list[plot_count])

            ...
            # Whatever you want to do with your plots
            ...

            plot_count += 1

        except:
            plot_count +=1

plt.show()
```